# Unable to bind the dynamic data into Angular Material select form

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am unable to display the data dynamically with Angular Material select form using Angular8. My code is below.

product.componet.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="productForm" (submit)="saveProduct($event)" novalidate> 

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <mat-label>Product Name</mat-label>
           <input matInput placeholder="Product Name" aria-label="Product Name" formControlName="Name" maxlength="70" required>
    </mat-form-field>
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                            <mat-label>Gender</mat-label>
                            <mat-select
                                placeholder="Select Gender" 
                                aria-label="Select Gender" 
                                (selectionChange)="onGenderSelectionChanged($event)"
                            >
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let s of genders" [value]="s.Code">
                                    <span *ngIf="!s.Code">
                                    </span>
                                    <span *ngIf="s.Code">
                                        {{s.Name}}
                                    </span>
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

Product.componet.ts:

```
genders: any = [
    '',
    {
      Code: "M",
      Name: "Male"
    },
    {
      Code: "F",
      Name: "Female"
    },
    {
      Code: "U",
      Name: "Unisex"
    }
  ];
this.productForm.setValue({
     Name : String = 'Test product',
     Gender: String = 'M(Male)'
})
```

I am able to display the product name but unable to display that drop down value which is binding dynamically. I need to display the drop down value dynamically using Angular 8.

Comment: There are a few things wrong with this post. They have been corrected in over a hundred of your prior posts, which is why you sometimes get downvotes. (1) Each of your file names have spelling errors. (2) Your files names are in quote blocks, but they are not quotes. (3) You keep saying that you are "explaining" your code, and you have been informed many times that this is not the right word. You are "showing" or "providing" your code. I am at a loss to understand why you are unwilling to heed basic, reasonable advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things which is wrong in the posted code:

1. You must use the `formControlName` for the gender control for the `<mat-select>` control:

Ex:

```
                Here
            \/\/\/\/\/\/
<mat-select formControlName="Gender" placeholder="Select Gender" aria-label="Select Gender" (selectionChange)="onGenderSelectionChanged($event)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let s of genders" [value]="s.Code">
     <span *ngIf="!s.Code"></span>
     <span *ngIf="s.Code"> {{s.Name}}</span>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

2. While setting value for the FormGroup not need to specify the datatype and,

```
this.productForm.setValue({
  Name : 'Test product',
  Gender: 'M'
});
```

Not `M(Male)` which is totally diff. from `M`, which you are using to bind the value of matselect.

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ts7f6j)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking try using to set the value as ""

```
<span>                                        
   {{s.Name}}                                    
</span>
```

And your array as

```
genders: any = [
    {
      Code: "",
      Name: ""
    },
    {
      Code: "M",
      Name: "Male"
    },
    {
      Code: "F",
      Name: "Female"
    },
    {
      Code: "U",
      Name: "Unisex"
    }
  ];
```

Setting the mat select value

```
<mat-select placeholder="Select Gender" aria-label="Select Gender"  (selectionChange)="onGenderSelectionChanged($event)" formControlName="Gender">
 <mat-option *ngFor="let s of genders" [value]="s.Code">
     <span *ngIf="!s.Code"></span>
     <span *ngIf="s.Code">
       {{s.Name}}
     </span>
 </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Add the formControlName to the mat select tag

```
formControlName="Gender"
```

Comment: Did not understand your answer. My requirement is when user will click on edit button the both values will be set to the respective field.

Comment: Ok updating the answer